# Can 'all' be used as a predicative complement?

Tags: pronouns, questions, predicative-complement

> "But what are you going to do with it [= dragon’s egg] when it's
>   hatched?" said Hermione. 
> "Well, I've bin doin' some readin', said
>   Hagrid, pulling a large book from under his pillow. "Got this outta
>   the library –– Dragon Breeding for Pleasure and Profit –– it's a bit
>   outta date, o' course, but **it's all** in here. Keep the egg in the
>   fire, 'cause their mothers breathe on ‘em, see, an' when it hatches,
>   feed it on a bucket o' brandy mixed with chicken blood every half
>   hour. An' see here –– how ter recognize diff'rent eggs –– what I got
>   there's a Norwegian Ridgeback. They're rare, them." 
> (Harry Potter
>   and the Sorcerer's Stone)

It looks like ‘all’ is a predicative complement over ‘it’. Yet I don’t find such usage in dictionaries. How do I see the ‘all’?

Comment: [It's all a mystery](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it's+all+a+mystery%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am consumed with envy at this gnomic recursion.

Comment: @StoneyB: Surely you mean ***all** this gnomic recursion!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers All one of it, over and over and over ... ∞

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It's all in here" means, approximately, "everything you need to know is contained in this work". The phrase is frequently used in response to a question or implicit question:

> How do I install a grounded wall outlet? —(*handing you a manual*) It's all in here.
>   I can't find the 1927 commerce data. —(*handing you a reference book*) It's all in here.

As FumbleFingers very wittily and economically points out, whenever *it* heads a response to a question or implicit question it often refers to the **answer**:

> Can 'all' be used as a predicative complement? —It's a mystery to me.

So the *it* Hagrid uses here is not co-referent with any previous *it*, but refers to the answer to the question which launched the discussion, "What are you going to do with it?"

As for *all*, McCawley 1998 has several pages (I'm sorry, I don't remember exactly where) on how *all* can be moved around. *All* may occur:

> at the beginning, in the determiner position: *All of it is here*.
>   after the noun/pronoun it modifies, in an appositive-adjective position: *It all is here*.
>   after the verb, in an adverb position: *It is all here*.

But they all have the same meaning. Or all of them have same meaning. Or they have all the same meaning.

Comment: Perhaps OP is confused because Hermione's "it" refers to the egg, and Hagrid's first "it" *(**it's** a bit outta date)* refers to the book. I think perhaps the easiest way to understand Hagrid's second "it" is to say ***it** = the answer to the question I'm addressing*. That works for all our current examples, and also covers "less-than-complete" responses like *"It's hard to say"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you're right about the confusion, and that your redefinition of my "substance" as "answer" is superior ...

Comment: Truth be told, even after [looking it up](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html), the exact meaning of "Predicative Complement" isn't clear to me. I really have no idea whether ***all*** counts as one in, for example, ["That's **all**, folks!"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that's+all+folks%22&oq=%22that's+all+folks%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.6283j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @FumbleFingers A predicative complement is a complement of the verb which is "predicated" of the subject: *He felt **ill***, *He looked **green***, and as you say *That is **all***.