# How does these 'all's be parsed?

Tags: pronouns

> [nurse, Madam Pomfrey] “And you have another visitor.”
>   “Oh,
>   good,” said Harry. “Who is it?”
>   Hagrid sidled through the door
>   as he spoke. As usual when he was indoors, Hagrid looked too big to be
>   allowed. He sat down next to Harry, took one look at him, and burst
>   into tears.
>   “**It’s — all — my — ruddy — fault!**”(1) he sobbed,
>   his face in his hands. “I told the evil git how ter get past Fluffy! I
>   told him! It was the only thing he didn’t know, an’ I told him! Yeh
>   could’ve died! **All fer a dragon egg!**(2) I’ll never drink again! I
>   should be chucked out an’ made ter live as a Muggle!”
>  (Harry
>   Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

‘It’s all my ruddy fault’ seem to be an example of Mr. StoneyB’s [explanation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/can-all-be-used-as-a-predicative-complement/8349#8349). Yet, case (2) is not clear to me. Is it the same case? Or is it a so called verbless clause: ‘all’ is the subject and ‘fer a dragon egg’ is a predicative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, *all* is not used as a determiner/pronoun but as an adverb with the sense of *entirely*. *All fer a dragon egg!* is not a 'sentence' but an adverbial phrase which is added to qualify the preceding sentence.

*All for X* is an ambiguous phrase. Often it has a simple literal meaning: “I did it all for you” means I did it entirely for you, not at all for myself. John Dryden titled his play about Antony and Cleopatra *All For Love, or The World Well Lost*, which has a pleasing double sense: his heroes acted entirely for love, and they gave up everything for love.

In this case, however, *all* has an overtone of *merely*—that is, it implies that what follows is trivial. “You could have died for nothing more important than a dragon egg.” “All for naught” and “All for nothing” have the same interpretation.